# Problemas con cargar la imagen en archivo HTML por guardado

Tags: html, html5

tengo un problema con mi pagina al momento de cargar la imagen en mi archivo HTML, resulta que cuando coloco la imagen, me muestra un icono con una x en el centro al momento de cargar la pagina. Yo puse la imagen que deseo mostrar en la **carpeta** donde se encuentra el **archivo HTML**. Pero todavía sigue sin mostrarme la imagen, tengo entendido que es por un error al salvar los cambios del archivo, y me gustaría saber si pueden porfavor ayudarme con esto. Aquí muestro el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <title>Curriculum</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

 <img src="curriculum/mi foto.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Si te aparece eso, es porque no encontró la imagen. Asegurarte que la imagen está dentro de la carpeta que se llama 'curriculum', también te recomiendo que tu imagen no lleve espacios, puedes cambiar el nombre del archivo a 'mi_foto.jpg' (también revisa la extensión si es en mayusculas o minúsculas)

Answer (score 0):

Mientras estés en desarrollo local, puedes forzar al navegador a no leer el caché usando uno de los siguientes `meta` en el `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

<meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">

<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">

<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

*(Solo necesitas colocar uno de ellos)*

---

**Comprueba que la ruta de la imagen es la correcta:** Dale clic derecho al ícono (que debería ser la imagen) y abrela en una nueva pestaña. Si no te sale tu imagen, debes comprobar la ruta y la extensión.

*Adicional*: La etiqueta `img` no necesita diagonal al final

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu apoyo, el método que me indicaste no me ayudo mucho, pero ya logre resolver el problema. Resulta que en las carpetas sin darme cuenta la tenia configurada de que no me mostrara los **formatos** de los archivos y mi error fue que yo al nombre de dicho archivo le escribí el formato, ocasionando que se repitiera el formato dos veces. Esto ocasiono que el programa ni el servidor pudieran accesar a la imagen específicamente.